# Many to many as map in fluent Nhibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way to map a many-to-many relationship using Fluent NHibernate to a dictionary?

Say I have the following (totally just made up) tables:

> Person (   Id INT,   Name
>   NVARCHAR(MAX) )
>
> Address (   Id INT,   StreetAddress
>   NVARCHAR(MAX) )
>
> PersonAddresses (   PersonId INT,
>   AddressId INT,   AddressType
>   NVARCHAR(MAX) )

```
public class Person
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IDictionary<string, Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map the addresses of a person to a dictionary property on the person entity that has the addresses as values and the AddressType from the PersonAddresses-table as the key. Is this at all possible using fluent NHibernate, if not, is it possible using the xml configuration? The problem I'm facing is that the key-column I want to map is in the join-table rather than in the referenced table.

Comment: How does the navigation work? Does your domain allow you to get to a person from an address, or only an address from a person?

Comment: It's only important to get to address from person, not the other way around.